# SQL Query to update conditional based upon column value in UNION data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 Different tables

```
1. JPMaster: It is a master table that has three columns. JPCode, JPName, and CourseCode. Basically one JPCode can have different CourseCodes in it. E.g.

JPCode  JPName  CourseCode
JP001   ABC     123
JP001   ABC     124
JP002   DEF     125
JP002   DEF     124

2. CourseMaster : Master tables for course

CourseCode  CourseName
123         Course1
124         Course2
125         Course3
126         Course4

3. EmployeeJPAssignment: Table where Employee can be assigned to JP, that means all course under that JP will be assigned to that Employee.

EmpNumber   JPCode
001         JP001
002         JP002

4. EmployeeCourseCompletion: Table where course completed by an employee is listed. Please note that Employee can complete a course which may be part JP that is assigned AND employee can directly complete a course that may not be part of any JPCode. E.g.

EmpNumber   CourseCode
001         123
002         125
002         126
```

**Note** `Course 126` is not a part of JPCode but the employee can complete directly a course which may not be part of JPCode.

E.g.

```
SELECT 
AC.EmpNumber AS employee_id
,AC.ActivityCode AS resourceId
,AC.RegistrationDate AS courseEnrollmentDate
,AC.EndDate AS courseCompletionDate
,JP.JPCode AS curriculaId
--,AC.LastUpdated AS lastUpdatedActivityCompletetion
--,AL.LastUpdated AS lastUpdatedActivityLibrary
--,CF.LastUpdated AS lastUpdatedCurrFile
--,JP.LastUpdated AS lastUpdatedJP
FROM SLTICurrFile CF
INNER JOIN SLTIJPStructure JP ON JP.JPCode = CF.CurriculaCode
Full Outer JOIN SLTIActivityCompletion AC ON AC.ActivityCode = JP.ActivityCode and AC.EmpNumber = CF.EmpNumber
INNER JOIN SLTIActivityLibrary AL ON AC.ActivityCode = AL.ActivityCode
WHERE (AC.EmpNumber = '001' )
order by AC.ActivityCode
```

Now it is only showing me result when the assigned course is completed but not showing those which are assigned but not completed

but not sure how to get results

Comment: Try it by `Join` - you can use left outer join for this solution

Comment: If I try left join.. I end up by cross join..

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read, and to write.

Comment: Title mentions update and union. I don't see either in SQL. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

If you need showing result when the assigned course is completed and separated item need for not assigned course and complete directly a course which may not be part of JPCode.

try this one for find result :

```
Select   EC.EmpNumber,CM.CourseName,ISNull(JM.JPName,'--') AS JPName
        ,ISNull(JM.JPCode,'CompleteDirectly') AS JPCode
From EmployeeCourseCompletion EC
    Left outer join EmployeeJPAssignment EA ON EC.EmpNumber=EA.JPCode
    Left outer join CourseMaster CM  ON CM.CourseCode = EC.CourseCode
    Left outer Join JPMaster JM ON JM.CourseCode = EC.CourseCode
Where EC.EmpNumber = 002
```

Result is :

```
EmpNumber|CourseName|JPName|JPCode
---------|----------|------|-----------
002      |Course3   |DEF   |JP002     
002      |Course4   |--    |CompleteDirectly
```

Your title is update! I can't find any  update you need in this question. if you need update from this query just use `where JM.JPName is Null`

```
Select   EC.EmpNumber,CM.CourseName,JM.JPName,JM.JPCode
From EmployeeCourseCompletion EC
    Left outer join EmployeeJPAssignment EA ON EC.EmpNumber=EA.JPCode
    Left outer join CourseMaster CM  ON CM.CourseCode = EC.CourseCode
    Left outer Join JPMaster JM ON JM.CourseCode = EC.CourseCode
Where JM.JPCode is Null
```

if you don't need other course use `where JM.JPCODE is not null`.

I hope this answer is useful for you.